# Fastlane plugin in swift

Tags: swift, fastlane

As of [2.69.0](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases/tag/2.69.0), fastlane now supports swift.

Is it possible to create plugins or actions in swift?

If yes, please provide an example, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, for now you can only create a `Fastfile.swift` that works with an auto generated version of fastlane's core actions and tools.